# How to determine which view to render in a controller action

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

Okay, I have a few different of ideas of how I would achieve this, but thought I would ask here in case someone has a better solution.

I have a SessionsController that has a login view and a widget_login view. I was wondering how to go about determining which view to render in the new action of SessionsController.

Right now, everything uses the standard login view. I was hoping to be able to render the widget_login view instead if the request is coming from my widget (reviewscontroller) which has a "Sign in" link on it. I don't want to use the referrer to determine this if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is feasible without seeing your code, but how about something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render(:action => 'new') }
    format.widget { render(:action => 'widget_login') }
end
```

Then in your widget link to `new.widget`.

Comment: Ok, I knew it had to be something simple. I'm an intern and have been learning a ton and my brain has to catch up sometimes. This should most definitely be feasible with my code. It's kind of funny to me I didn't think of this because I used code exactly like this to render the iframe for the widget.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the action code:

```
render :layout => 'my_layout'
```

if there was already a `render` call, modify it adding the `:layout` parameter.